# Display mysql results in columns alpabetically

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE: Sorry my question wasnt clear the first time, hopefully this makes more sense.
I have a query that lists all the categories, at the moment it's iterating through and placing it inside a paragraph tag.

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_name');

foreach($data as $row) {
echo '
<p><a href="category/'.$row['category_slug'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</a></p>';
}
```

How can I place all the names in columns alphabetically, ie those that start with A go in one column, b goes in another column and so on. Something like:

A--------------B--------C

Action--------Blah----Cartoons

Adventure---Blah----Comics

I could create a column then do a query in each one but that would mean a query for every letter of the alphabet. Can I acheive this with one query.

Comment: do you mean in a table? How come you dont parse it insde a `table`?

Comment: @CodeGodie should really be tabular, but I'm going to display it in responsive columns so want to put it around divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not clear.

Quick solution:

```
 $data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_name');
 echo '<table><tr><td>';
 $curIndexLatter='';
 foreach($data as $row) {
    if ($curIndexLatter != '' && $curIndexLatter!=substr($row['category_name'],0,1) )
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo '<p><a href="category/'.$row['category_slug'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</a></p>';

    $curIndexLatter=substr($row['category_name'],0,1); 
}
echo '</td</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed! Sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 2):

I think what he wants is something like this:

```
$wordArray = array('august', 'March', 'october', 'April', 'January', 'February', 'June', 'July');

foreach($wordArray as $word){

    // Get first letter uppercased
    $letter = ucfirst(substr($word, 0, 1));

    $ordered[$letter][] = $word;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ordered);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output is:

```
    Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => august
            [1] => April
        )

    [M] => Array
        (
            [0] => March
        )

    [O] => Array
        (
            [0] => october
        )

    [J] => Array
        (
            [0] => January
            [1] => June
            [2] => July
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [0] => February
        )

)
```

Then you can construct a table like @CodeGodie say it and you will be done :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need something where you define the order of display while you're grabbing the data and displaying it.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_name ORDER BY `category` ASC";

$row = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($row);

//Count number of pets
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

//Figure out how many pets to put in each column
$columncount = ceil($count/3);
$lastcolumncount = $count - $columncount *2;
$middlecolumnstart = $count - $columncount - $lastcolumncount +1;
$lastcolumnstart = $count-$lastcolumncount +1;

//Put the pets into three columns
if ($row): 
    $count = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="column">
        <?php
        foreach ($rows as $cat):
            $count ++;

            if($count == $middlecolumnstart) {
                echo '</div><div class="column">';
            }

            if($count == $lastcolumnstart) {
                echo '</div><div class="column last-column">';
            }

           ?>

            <a href=""><?php echo $cat->category_name; ?></a>

        <?php 
        endforeach;
    endif; ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.column {
    width:180px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:26px;
}

.olumn a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:10px;

}

.column.last-column {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: i think the idea of handling the display in css is a good one.

Comment: Haven't tried any of the above but this looks like what I need. You're defining how many in a column, I'd need it to be as many returned per letter.

Comment: can you add comments in your code to explain how these are getting set? `$columncount`, `$lastcolumncount`, `$middlecolumnstart`,`$lastcolumnstart `

Answer (score 0):

First, you **sort** it like this:

```
$array = $data->fetch_assoc();
$arr = array();
foreach ($array as $n) {
    $f = substr($n, 0, 1);
    $arr[$f] = array();
    foreach ($array as $n2) {
        $f2 = substr($n2, 0, 1);
        if ($f2 === $f) {
           array_push($arr[$f], $n2);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Then you can iterate it to **build** your columns, like this:

```
$cols = "";
foreach ($arr as $letter => $names) {
    $column = "<div class='column'>";
    $column .= "<h3>$letter</h3>";
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $column .= "<div>$name</div>";
    }
    $column .= "</div>";
    $cols .= $column;
}
?>
```

now on **HTML**:

```
<body>
    <?= $cols ?>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
.column{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```